# 'class SoftSerial' has no member named 'readString' ! Arduino DigiSpark attiny85 SoftSerial.h SoftwareSerial.h NeoPixel

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

i'm using Arduino IDE 1.8.12, it's setup to use digispark libs (i think), don't remember exactly what i did, watched a video online some many moths ago.

i have an issue with my sketch, when i try to compile it it gives me this error:

```
 error: 'class SoftSerial' has no member named 'readString'

     dataIn = bluetooth.readString();

                        ^

exit status 1
'class SoftSerial' has no member named 'readString'
```

I am not that surprised because the original code was written for an Arduino and it used SoftwareSerial.h instead of SoftSerial.h but for some strange reason i can't load or get to work with softwareserial now, i have the libs in arduino folder but i don't know if it's even possible to load them and work with them since i've set the IDE to work with digispark.

The other solution would be to find a way to do "readString" in a way that SoftSerial recognises, i'm not sure if that is possible either.

PLEASE HELP!

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h> // NeoPixel Lib
#include <SoftSerial.h>  // Serial Lib


#define LED_PIN    1
#define LED_COUNT 30

SoftSerial bluetooth(3, 4); // RX TX
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);


int brightness = 100;   //
int redColor = 0;
int greenColor = 0;
int blueColor = 0;

String dataIn = "";   //

unsigned long timer1 = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin (9600);
  strip.begin();           // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
  strip.show();            // Turn OFF all pixels ASAP
  strip.setBrightness(brightness); // Set BRIGHTNESS to about 1/5 (max = 255)

}

void loop(){
  if (bluetooth.available() > 0);{
    dataIn = bluetooth.readString();
    delay(20);
//    Serial.println(dataIn);
    if (dataIn.startsWith("1")){
      delay(10);
      String R = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("R") + 1, dataIn.indexOf("G"));
      redColor = R.toInt();
      Serial.println(R);
      String G = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("G") + 1, dataIn.indexOf("B"));
      greenColor = G.toInt();
      Serial.println(G);
      String B = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("B") +1, dataIn.indexOf("E"));
      blueColor = B.toInt();
      Serial.println(B);
    }

    else if (dataIn.startsWith("2")){
      String stringBrightness = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("2") + 1, dataIn.length());
      brightness = stringBrightness.toInt();
      strip.setBrightness(brightness); 
      Serial.println(brightness);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < LED_COUNT; i++){
      strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.Color(greenColor, redColor, blueColor));
    
    }
  }

  strip.show();
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: k, so i found out a few things... i made a copy of the folder softwareSerial (the libreray) in a diffrent place where the IDE is looking for libs when i set it to work with digispark, now it finds the lib but it cannot read the "readstring" when it compiles, says it cannot find it...

Comment: and yet if i move the ide to work and compile for digispark PRO it compiles, but it cannot load the software because of memory issues....

Comment: Yeah, String class uses a lot of memory.  There's probably a good reason they left readString out.  If you want to work with the ATTINY85 you're going to have to learn to live without some of the crutches and write small code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply implement the same functionality in your sketch using read().

readString blocks for a set amount of time.  It freezes your sketch waiting on the transmission to complete for 1 second.  This isn't great for most sketches.  Most of the time it would be better to implement a non-blocking read.  There are also big issues with using the String class on smaller microcontrollers like the UNO and especially the tiny85 in the digiSpark.  It would be best on that platform to stick to c-style strings.  But here's how to mimic readString if that's really what you want to do.

```
String myReadString() {

   unsigned long startTime = millis();
   char c = 0;
   String message = "";
   while (c!= '\n' && (millis() - startTime <= 1000)){
      if(bluetooth.available()){
          c = bluetooth.read();
          message += c;
      }
   }
   return message;
```

And then use it like this:

```
if (bluetooth.available() > 0);{
    dataIn = myReadString();
```

Again, this isn't a particularly good thing to do because all of that string concatenation will shoot holes in the tiny amount of memory you have on the 85. That's probably why they didn't implement it in the libraries for it. If I were you I'd spend some time learning how to work with serial data.  Google "Robin2 serial input basics" for one good place to read from the Arduino forum.  But if you really insist on String class then there's a function that will do what readString does.

Comment: "Robin2 serial input basics" this was an excelent read , thank you very much, 1 thing remains to figure out. in the next comment

Comment: DUDE THANK YO SO MUCH, I'VE DONE IT, IT WORKS EVERYTHING I NEED IT WAS IN THAT ARTICLE